# Remove OneToOne unidirectionnal relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called Upload and another one called Shop

The Shop can have only one Upload

```
class Shop
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Upload
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vendor\SystemBundle\Entity\Upload",cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $myfile;
}

class Upload
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string $path
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string")
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var string $uniqId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uniqId", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $uniqId;

    /**
     * @var integer $size
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="size", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $size;

    /**
     * @var string $extension
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="extension", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $extension;
}
```

! Because my class Shop is generated automatically, i can't specify the relation into my class Upload

Is there a way to remove the relation and delete the corresponding item.

For now, if i want to remove my entity Upload, it says i have a Foreign Key contraint (which is normal), so I am trying to remove the relation directly from Shop, but I don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

You generated it using the `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity` command?

If you want to remove the relation remove the part

```
/**
 * @var Upload
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vendor\SystemBundle\Entity\Upload",cascade={"all"})
 */
private $myfile;
```

and then do

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Your\Entity\Path\
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

So it re-creates the getters and setters and delete the constrain from the db

Comment: Hi, I want to keep the relation, but want to clear the related item.Let's say i selected an "Upload" them I want to remove it

Comment: What if you do get the shop instance you want to remove the upload, do the getUpload() method and then `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove($upload); $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();` ? By default it's nullable.